# AFHTTPREquestOperation doesn't work on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ftp, afnetworking

I'm trying to compile application on my iPad. I'm using AFNetworking to get list of files on my FTP. Application works on simulator, but when i start it on iPad i get (null) content of file with list. Here's code:

```
- (void) getListOfFiles {

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"ftp://anonymous@ftphost/"]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list"];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:YES];


[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSHTTPURLResponse *response) {
         NSLog(@"Success %@",operation.response);
}
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                 }];

[operation start];
NSString *content  = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  error:nil];

NSLog (@"%@",content);
}
```

So variable content = (null) only on iPad, and on Simulator everything is fine. Please help, i have lost any hope )

Comment: Where is placed ftp server? Asking to determine if ftp server is not reachable from device...

Comment: It looks like you don't fully understand asynchronous callbacks. You need to read the contents of `path` inside the success block.

Comment: ftp is reachable from ipad (safari), i'm getting success message but file is still blanc, how can i read content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the AFHTTP*Operations are all asynchronous by default.

this is proper, since synchronous(blocking) calls block the main thread

you are starting the operation and take file content directly afterwards. This can't work reliably because the start call is ASYNC and only STARTS the op but doesnt wait for it

**either wait** for it ... **which is BAD** as it blocks the thread:

```
[operation start];
[operation waitUntilDone];
```

or **MUCH BETTER** modify getFiles to **work asynchronously**:

```
- (void) getListOfFiles {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"URL"]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list"];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:YES];


    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSHTTPURLResponse *response) {
             NSLog(@"Success %@",operation.response);
             NSString *content  = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  error:nil];
             NSLog (@"%@",content);
        }
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: Ok, so now i getting "Success" message, but content is still null

Comment: did you do it async or with the wait hack? :)

Comment: just tried with url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558209/afhttprequestoperation-doesnt-work-on-ipad and it works fine with this code.. know that OF COURSE content is nil if the server answers with nil ;)

Comment: i do it async, as you said, but how's that possible,that app works on simulator (getting content of files) and return nil on iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. I can't write to bundle directory, so i nee to use next code instead:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoiesDomain(NSDocumentDirectory,NSCachesDirectory,YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stingByAppendingPathComponent:@"list"];
```